# IDEA don't support scala?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

idea: 11.1.2
build: #IU:117.418
**macbook**

compile err:
javac: 无效的标志： /Users/shijinkui/workerspace/scalaTest/src/main/java/Test.scala

i find that the scala compiler always working.

thanks.

screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: i have resole this problem. 

setting --> IDE Setting  --> File Types  --> scala file --> add Registered Patterns  

add *.scala

that is all. 哈哈

thanks all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you need to install the Scala plugin? http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=1347

Tutorial for Scala in IntelliJ: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/SCA/Getting+Started+with+IntelliJ+IDEA+Scala+Plugin

General Documentation for Scala in IntelliJ: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+for+IntelliJ+IDEA

Your Project:

[image]

The Tutorial:

[image]

Why it does not work?: You are **not** following the tutorial.

Comment: and what is your problem now?

Comment: the editor tips error:compile err: javac: 无效的标志： /Users/shijinkui/workerspace/scalaTest/src/main/java/Test.scala

Comment: Did you follow the tutorial? Up to which step?

Comment: yes.  all follow step by step.  i conf scala compiler, but the code is compiled by javac

Comment: All the steps? Or up to which one (step number)? Can you upload a screenshot of your IntelliJ showing the error?

Comment: Added images to my answer, your screenshot does not match the tutorial ¿why you say you are following it, when you are not?

Comment: http://www.pusuo.net/java/Snip20120712_8.png  http://www.pusuo.net/java/Snip20120712_9.png http://www.pusuo.net/java/Snip20120712_10.png  http://www.pusuo.net/java/Snip20120712_11.png   http://www.pusuo.net/java/Snip20120712_12.png

Comment: i have resole this problem. 

setting --> IDE Setting  --> File Types  --> scala file --> add Registered Patterns  

add *.scala

that is all. 哈哈

thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

i have resole this problem.

setting --> IDE Setting  --> File Types  --> scala file --> add Registered Patterns

add *.scala

that is all. 哈哈